# Remove first character with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would I go about removing the first character from this.className in the below line? 
The first variable will be _ and then a number. I just want the number to be assigned to className.

```
className = this.className;
```

Furthermore I am changing `"$('.inter').html(window[link[className]]);"` to use an array instead of the className variable. Is the below code the correct way to use an array with the index as a variable?

```
$('.inter').html(window[link[className]]);
```

Comment: Don't use reserved keywords like className as variable names.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

No need to use jQuery for that, just plain ol' javascript using [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
var trimmed = this.className.substring(1);
```

Comment: +1 for no useless jQuery, people always forget about the JavaScript

Comment: @jahroy `substr` and it was my initial though before writing the answer down. Only reason I didn't is that it was never formally included in the language specification.